# Properly closing a thread, that runs possible long for loops, during the closure of an application

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

So, I have a class that manipulates an image, i.e, horizontal mirroring or vertical mirroring etc. This class runs in its separate thread.

```
m_imageMirrorer = new ImageMirrorer();
m_imageMirrorer->moveToThread(&m_thread);
m_thread.start();
connect(&m_thread, &QThread::finished, this, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

Now, to properly close the thread when the application is randomly closed by the user, I have added the following code in the destructor.

```
    m_thread.quit();
    if(!m_thread.wait(3000)) //Wait until it actually has terminated (max. 3 sec)
    {
        m_thread.terminate(); //Thread didn't exit in time, probably deadlocked, terminate it!
        m_thread.wait(); //We have to wait again here!
    }

    if(m_imageMirrorer)
    {
        delete m_imageMirrorer;
    }
```

I actually initially tried without using `quit()`, `wait()`, `terminate()` of `m_thread` in the destructor at all. But then it was always giving the error `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`. `deleteLater` didn't do anything to avoid that particular crash.

Am I doing it correctly now?

Thanks.

Comment: Forcibly terminating a thread is usually a bad idea. Instead have an (atomic) flag that you set, and which the thread checks if it should exit or not.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the reply. Is possible for you to give a small example.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you would do this kind of task with an atomic. However Qt already integrated a mechanism that does just that.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isInterruptionRequested which is triggered by requestInterruption.

While running your tasks you can integrate a check `if (QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested())` and then just end your calculations / tasks cleanly. This adds overhead so it shouldn't be checked every nanosecond.